# Showing that $x^3 + 7x +2 $ is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

I want to show that $f(x) = x^3 + 7x +2 \in \mathbb Z[x]$ is irreducible.

**My idea is:**

Let $a$ be a root of it then $2 = -a^3 - 7a$ then $a$ is a divisor of $2$ in $\mathbb Z$ therefore candidates for $a$ are $\pm 1, \pm 2.$ But then how can I complete? could someone clarify this to me please?

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is reducible, then it can be written as a product of linear and quadratic factors (this relies on the fact that $f$ is of degree $3$).  Then, use the rational roots theorem.

Comment: Why do you state that $a$ need to be in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr because 2 in $\mathbb Z.$

Comment: As an example, $(2x+1)^2$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}$, but its zeros are not in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I do not see how I will use the degree 3 idea as Z is not a field

Comment: I'm not sure why $\mathbb{Z}$ not being a field is concerning.  Regardless, Gauss' lemma implies that irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is the same as primitive and irreducibility in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, so you can work over the field $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Your polynomial is an increasing function of $x$ and has a single real root between $-1$ and $0$. If it were reducible it would have a linear factor, and none is available. (You could say that if it has a real/rational root that root is between $-1$ and $0$ and is therefore not an integer).

Comment: Assume that $f$ is reducible, write it as a product of two factors $(mx-a)$ and $(nx^2+bx+c)$. The main coefficient of $f$, of the product, is $1$ so $mn=1$ implies $m$ is $\pm 1$. Change sign in both factors to reduce to the case $m=1$. Then $a$ is a root of the factor $(x-a)$, so it is a root of $f$. As above, only divisors of the free coefficient are in discussion for $a$. But none of them is a root of $f$.

Comment: $x^3 + 7x +2$ is irreducible mod 7 because it has not root there.